# MVC - Creating a Model for a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, web, model

I'm fairly new to MVC and am looking for some advice in relation to creating Models for online forms.  I'm trying to convert a paper based form into an online version.

Link to form: [Extract of form](http://www.hefjones.co.uk/files/form.pdf)

So I'm looking for some advice on setting up the model:

1. What do I name the properties of the model?  I've done simple forms
   in the past with properties such as Name, Address, Postcode etc -
   which are easy to label in the model, but with more complex
   questions what would be best practice on labelling the properties?
2. How do I handle 2+ part questions such as Questions 1,4 and 6 in the
   attached form?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The best place for you to start would be on MSDN, where the naming conventions are clearly stated to make it easy for everyone who works on it and that follows best practice:

[MSDN Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx)

As for the 2+ part questions, if you want them to select 1 you can use a RadioButton, or a DropDownList. If you want them to select more than one you can sue a CheckBoxList

A list of helpers and more can be found here
[Rendering a Form in ASP.NET MVC Using HTML Helpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd410596(v=vs.100).aspx)

Finally [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor) is a nice blog by ScottGu about the @ razor syntax with html helpers